# CSS 3 : Correct "transition-property" for translate operation

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am using the following code  to achieve a simple `translation` of an object when its clicked.

```js
$('#div1').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('pushObject');
});
```

```css
#div1 {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:green;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#div1:hover {
    background-color:red;
}

.pushObject {
    transform: translate(250px, 0px);
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

It works as expected, and I get a smooth 0.5 second animation for `all` the transitions(in this case `translate` as well as `hover`) as I have set the `transition-property` value in css to `all`.

What I want is to limit this 0.5s `Transition` to `translate` only, and not to `hover`.

This can be achieved by setting the correct `transition-property` in css, but I am unable to find the correct value.

So what will be the correct value of `transition-property` here so that the animation applies to `translate` only and not to any other `transition`.

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mz2b/).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In your `transform: translate(250px, 0px)` declaration, the property is called `transform` and the value of that property is the `translate(250px, 0px)` function.

The correct value of `transition-property` is therefore `transform`:

```
#div1 {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:green;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/7mz2b/1)

```js
$('#div1').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('pushObject');
});
```

```css
#div1 {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
   
    background-color:green;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s ease;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}
#div1:hover {
    background-color:red;
}

.pushObject {
    transform: translate(250px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(250px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(250px, 0px);
    -o-transform: translate(250px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate(250px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: Oh, that was simple, I was just trying to target the standard css properties like margin etc., coz I just thought that it will be affecting those.